# Refresh Excel Queries using java

Tags: java, excel, algorithm, apache-poi

I have a complex excel sheet with lot of formulae and pivot table. It pulls out data from database using queries and then pivots and other formulae operate on that data and create rest of the worksheets in the same excel. Manually to do this one needs to click on the refresh button which refreshes the entire sheet.

Now what i need to do is to refresh the excel sheet using java code. I have used POI etc but i have no idea where to find this functionality to refresh the excel queries. I tried hard looking into this forum but still not the perfect solution. The overall idea is to create a program which will refresh this sheet every 30 mins using windows scheduler where i will schedule my java program.

I have no idea for VB.. if anyone has better way to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is an X-Y problem.  You need to solve problem X (refresh regularly).  You've thought of a solution Y (use Java+scheduler) you think you can implement but have hit a roadblock.

You could start to learn about Office automation and probably finish the way you are doing.  But it will be a lot of work, and less reliable, than:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-connected-imported-data-e76a38b0-e2e1-400b-9f2f-c87b9b18c092#bmautomatically_refresh_data_at_regular